# Encrypting files in using CommonCrypt CCrypto AES256 - cannot decrypt some files

Tags: swift, cocoa, encryption, cryptography, nsdata

I want to encrypt some files using AES256 in my cocoa application.
The resulting files should be as small as possible.

Here's my code:

```
 static func encryptFile(pathToFile:String, destinationPath:String, key:String) -> Bool {

    var error: NSError?
    let fileContents = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToFile, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)
    if let fileContents = fileContents {
        println("Trying to encrypt file \(pathToFile)")
        let startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let encryptedContents = FileEncryptor.AES256Encryption(fileContents, key: key)
        println("ENCRYPTION TIME: \(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime)")

        if let encryptedContents = encryptedContents {
            var writeError: NSError?

            if (encryptedContents.writeToFile(pathToFile, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: &writeError)) {
                return true
            } else {
                if (writeError != nil) {
                    println("Cannot write to file \(pathToFile). Error: \(writeError)")
                } else {
                    println("Cannot write to file \(pathToFile)")
                }
                return false
            }
        } else {
            return false
        }

    } else {
        println("Unable to read file \(pathToFile). Error: \(error)");
        return false
    }

}


static func AES256Encryption(dataToEncrypt:NSData, key:String) -> NSData? {
        let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
        let keyBytes         = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(keyData.bytes)
        print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length), keyData   = \(keyData)")

        let dataLength    = size_t(dataToEncrypt.length)
        let dataBytes     = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(dataToEncrypt.bytes)
        print("dataLength  = \(dataLength)")

        let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
        let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(cryptData!.mutableBytes)
        let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData!.length)

        let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
        let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
        let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
        let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCModeCBC)

        var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

        let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes, keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes, dataLength,
            cryptPointer, cryptLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)

        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
            //  let x: UInt = numBytesEncrypted
            cryptData!.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)
            print("cryptLength = \(numBytesEncrypted)")

            return cryptData

        } else {
            print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
            return nil
        }
    }
```

I have an issue with two things:
1. Encrypted file content look like [small part of the file]:

```
a56f 707a 24cb e965 08dd be3d 1a0d 9e7b
b73f c982 2014 fdae fa29 c63d 4588 ee29
7b03 5fb2 96a5 00be 2871 e3e8 af23 4eac
```

I would rather have it like:

```
ã.FrÚQ÷¬_ÄC¯Q%,™˜$žKÝôÙ„gC€È•GBvn&­V9&´fÓ
```

2. I cannot decrypt some of the files.
   Most of them are fine, however some are not. I've been looking for some kind of pattern, and the only thing I have found is that in most cases, the files which are correct, are larger when encrypted then they are when decrypted/original.

Here's a function I use to decrypt:

```
static func decryptFile(pathToFile:String, destinationPath:String, key:String) -> Bool {
    var error: NSError?
    let fileContents = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathToFile, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &error)
    if let fileContents = fileContents {
        println("Trying to decrypt file \(pathToFile)")
        let startTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
        let decryptedContents = FileEncryptor.AES256Decryption(fileContents, key: key)
        println("DECRYPTION TIME: \(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 - startTime)")
        return NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(destinationPath, contents:decryptedContents, attributes:nil)
    } else {
        println("Unable to read file \(pathToFile). Error: \(error)");
        return false
    }

}

static func AES256Decryption(data:NSData, key: String) -> NSData? {
    let keyData: NSData! = (key as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSData!
    let keyBytes         = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(keyData.bytes)
    print("keyLength   = \(keyData.length)")

    let dataLength    = size_t(data.length)
    let dataBytes     = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(data.bytes)
    print("dataLength  = \(dataLength), ")

    let cryptData    = NSMutableData(length: Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
    let cryptPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(cryptData!.mutableBytes)
    let cryptLength  = size_t(cryptData!.length)

    let keyLength              = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES256)
    let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCDecrypt)
    let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
    let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding + kCCModeCBC)

    var numBytesEncrypted :size_t = 0

    let cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
        algoritm,
        options,
        keyBytes, keyLength,
        nil,
        dataBytes, dataLength,
        cryptPointer, cryptLength,
        &numBytesEncrypted)

    if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) {
        //  let x: UInt = numBytesEncrypted
        cryptData!.length = Int(numBytesEncrypted)

        return cryptData
    } else {
        print("Error: \(cryptStatus)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

Almost all of the code has been taken from SO, it seems to work ok, apart from these issues I have.
The password I use is same for all of the files.

Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
About issue 2. It seems the code I used was prepared for ECB mode which I have changed to CBC. This means I have to increase size of the encrypted data. After making this change, almost all of the files work perfectly, apart from one... which worked ok when using the smaller value. Damn.